# Crash when installing application leading to weird "No such app found" entry in drawer and forced reboot

Tags: lineageos, crashes, intents

A few days ago I installed a app from an .apk file. Unfortunately, my phone decided to die during the installation process. Since then I have a weird entry in my drawer looking like this:

[image: Weird entry in app drawer]

If I click on it, I get a toast saying "No such app found". This alone wouldn't bother me but since then my phone also crashes after about two minutes after it started.

I've tried investigating this problem but I couldn't find anything really helpful. The only thing I found is a [post from StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7773360/what-exactly-happens-when-i-install-an-android-application) describing what happens when you install an application. Based on this I think there went something wrong with the intent registration, corrupting a intent register or something like that.

What I've tried so far is cleaning the cache and installing and uninstalling the app again. When the app is installed again, the weird entry in the launcher disappears and even after the app is uninstalled, it doesn't reappear. However, my phone still keeps crashing and after a reboot it reappears.

Does anyone have a idea what is going on here and how to fix this? I would be very thankful for any help :).

Additional information:

- Device: Samsung Galaxy S7 (herolte)
- ROM: LineageOS 15.1 (Android 8.1.0)
- Rooted: Yes

EDIT:
I've also already tried getting the logcat output before the crash but unfortunately it shows nothing really interesting and I think the reason for the crash is not included because it crashes before a write to the logcat takes place.
Also, for clarification, I would like to avoid a factory reset.

EDIT 2:
I've now tried rebooting into safe mode. The drawer entry persists, but the system doesn't crash here. Also, when long pressing on the app and selecting "App info", the launcher crashes with the following entry in logcat:

```
06-17 18:16:00.960  4599  6669 I ActivityManager: START u0 {act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=market://details?id=<redacted>} from uid 10026
06-17 18:16:00.960  6727  6727 D AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
06-17 18:16:00.961  6727  6727 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-17 18:16:00.961  6727  6727 E AndroidRuntime: Process: org.lineageos.trebuchet, PID: 6727
06-17 18:16:00.961  6727  6727 E AndroidRuntime: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=market://details?id=<redacted> }
06-17 18:16:00.961  6727  6727 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1937)
06-17 18:16:00.961  6727  6727 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1616)
06-17 18:16:00.961  6727  6727 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4487)
06-17 18:16:00.961  6727  6727 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.android.launcher3.Launcher.startActivityForResult(Launcher.java:1916)
06-17 18:16:00.961  6727  6727 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4445)
06-17 18:16:00.961  6727  6727 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4806)
06-17 18:16:00.961  6727  6727 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4774)
06-17 18:16:00.961  6727  6727 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.android.launcher3.InfoDropTarget.startDetailsActivityForInfo(InfoDropTarget.java:70)
06-17 18:16:00.961  6727  6727 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.android.launcher3.popup.SystemShortcut$AppInfo$1.onClick(SystemShortcut.java:97)
06-17 18:16:00.961  6727  6727 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6294)
06-17 18:16:00.961  6727  6727 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24770)
06-17 18:16:00.961  6727  6727 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
06-17 18:16:00.961  6727  6727 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-17 18:16:00.961  6727  6727 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
06-17 18:16:00.961  6727  6727 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
06-17 18:16:00.961  6727  6727 E AndroidRuntime:        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
06-17 18:16:00.961  6727  6727 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
06-17 18:16:00.961  6727  6727 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
06-17 18:16:00.965  4599  6669 W ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity org.lineageos.trebuchet/com.android.launcher3.searchlauncher.SearchLauncher
06-17 18:16:00.970  4599  6781 W DropBoxManagerService: Dropping: system_app_crash (1567 > 0 bytes)
06-17 18:16:00.971  4599  4614 I ActivityManager: Showing crash dialog for package org.lineageos.trebuchet u0
```

Comment: You have to use logcat. If you know that an auto-restart is imminent it is best to put the device plugged Into PC and logcat output being redirected to a file. Once restart happens, check the contents of the file from bottom to top. Errors or warnings should be the first to look after. As for a fix, are you willing to try a factory reset? A lot of times, a reset fixes manifestation of a problem (not the problem itself if it is due to a bug).

Comment: @Firelord Ahh yeah, forgot to mention I've already tried getting the logcat output before the crash but unfortunately it shows nothing really interesting and I think the reason for the crash is not included because it crashes before a write to the logcat takes place. As for the factory reset this would most likely solve the problem but I don't want to loose my app's data :/. Would you know a way to backup my apps despite the crashing?

Comment: Assuming your device is rooted you can try to check the various places mentioned here: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/200983/2241

Comment: @Robert Thank you for the hint. I've checked all locations mentioned there but my app doesn't turn up in any of there lists.